# DAX measure to multiply single value to multiple unique values in power pivot

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have a data set prepared as this:

[image]

As you can observe the values in "Fuel column" has been repeatedly  entered from each row for the purpose of calculating  the fuel ratio (row-by-row) easily.

What I wanted is to create a measure to calculate the fuel ratio WITHOUT entering same values over again and I can multiply to all the unit ratio row-by-row.

Hope you can assist me with some workaround ideas.

Comment: YOur fuel prices will be constant(205) for every row or will it be some other value?

Comment: No. It will be different every other day.

Comment: If you dont want to repeat FUEL value, then where you store this info? Do you have additional table in your powerbi model or so?

Comment: Yes. I have separate and dedicated table for fuel alone.

Comment: you can import the value from there